# How to find 58 bytes of hexa checksum in java

Tags: java, checksum

I want to know how to find  Hexa checksum using java code

`5AA50000000100000001000100020003000400050006000700080009001000110012001300140015001600170018001900200021002200230024`

​

I tried using checksum interface it returns a long value

```
byte[] bytes=value.getBytes();
Checksum cs = new CRC32();
       
   cs.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
  System.out.println(cs.getValue()+"check sum");
```

​
Header(10)  Start Byte(2)   Source Addr(4)  Destination Addr(4)
Payload (48)    Data1 - Data24
Checksum(1) Least 8bit of 58Byte Sum Value
EndByte(1)  0x20

how to achieve 5B as a checksum

Comment: now check the question

Comment: OK now it makes more sense. Do you have any hints about what kind of checksum it could be? Whatever it is, it shouldn't be a crc32, since those are not 8bit and using 8 bits from a crc32 makes very little sense. I expected it to be either a simple sums of the bytes, or the XOR (these are common for 8 bit checksums), but they didn't give me 5B. It's not clear which subset of the bytes is supposed to checksummed either, maybe all of it? Or skip header? Only payload?

Comment: Without knowing which protocol is involved, it is probably not possible to calculate the checksum. How to convert a hex-decimal string into a byte array with Java looks like a secondary problem. (Which there are several SO questions and answers)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `value` seems to be a hexadecimal representation of bytes, 2 characters forming one byte value in base 16; "5A" = (byte) 170. To get those bytes:

```
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(value, 16).toByteArray();
```

Note that this hacky conversion requires that the value does not start with "00".

As I believe that checksums of two arrays where one has preceeding zeroes are different:

```
int zeroes = 58 - bytes.length;
if (zeroes > 0) {
    byte[] bytes2 = new byte[58];
    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, bytes2, zeroes, bytes.length);
    bytes = bytes2;
}
```

---

***After comment, some further research:***

Hex conversion best done with:

```
    final int N = value.length() / 2;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(value.substring(i*2, i*2 + 2), 16);
    }
```

I tried CRC8 as that would give an 8 bit result. Did not work.
Short endianness (endian byte order) also did not work.

The CRC32 gives 0x8a82c8cb which cannot easily be converted to 0x5b

That the checksum is a single byte value is hard to believe. Hence my conjecture for CRC8.

Sometimes precalculated CRC32 tables are used, and those may vary.

**No solution here!**

Comment: But I'm getting long value in return how to get 5B .The returned value is 2323826891

Comment: CRC32 should return a 32 bits value, an `int` (2323826891 is). It might be that the bytes actually are a `short[]` with the wrong endianness (least and most significant bytes reversed). As the original string is 116 bytes (= 2 * 58) long.

Comment: The reason for my "short" guess stems from values like "0023". You could swap pairs of bytes. But then a bit of more intelligent research would be better.

Comment: can yo send the actual working code please how to get 5B  as a checksum for the mentioned hexadecimal